# Div hide not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a div, and I can't seem to get it working properly. Here's my code:

```
<head>
<title>Home - Chrome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function 1Hide() {
document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
</div>
<a onclick="1Hide" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
height: 100;
width: 700;
margin: 30 auto 0 auto;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers cannot start with numbers. Change `1Hide` to something like `Hide1` instead. Moreover, to call a function, you add parenthesis to the end of the identifier like so:

`Hide1();`.

This will call the function. Your HTML should look like the following:

```
<a onclick="Hide1();" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a>
```

Notice the operator `()` appended to the end of the function name. Whenever you want to *call* functions this is the syntax you use.

Answer (score 3):

Three issues:

- Variable/function names cannot start with a number
- You don't call `()` the function
- The numeric CSS values should have a suffix such as `px`

Answer (score 2):

First, use parentheses (to make a function call on click). Then, start your function name with a letter:

```
<script>
    function div1Hide() {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
<a onclick="div1Hide()" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery's hide function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) like so:

```
$('#myHideButton').click(function() {
   $('#div1').hide();
});
```